# cannot curl/crawl https from soundcloud

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https

I am trying to crawl the data from soundcloud.com... But the problem is that it works for http... Whenever i enter a https url, the page is blank and there are no results, there are no errors too

I have a shared hosting in which i have configured my php.ini with `curl.cainfo=/php/cacert.pem`

My curl code looks like this...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/php/cacert.pem");
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
if($contents === FALSE) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);


return $contents;
```

I have downloaded the certificates from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
and copied them in myfolder/php...

Please help...

Comment: did you check if $contents is a boolean FALSE, which curl returns when the exec() call fails? `if ($contents === FALSE) { die(curl_error($ch); }` will tell you what the problem is. NEVER assume success. "blank" doesn't mean much.

Comment: I'll check it sometime

Comment: I added the code... Still nothing... Just a blank page. No error in the log too...

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $contents = curl_exec($ch);
 if($contents === FALSE) {
  die(curl_error($ch));
 }
 curl_close($ch);`

Comment: I tried this and it gives me "You are being redirected" in https soundcloud

Comment: so use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION !